# Python Elastic Reindex : failed to parse field [source]

Tags: python, json, parsing, elasticsearch

I am trying to reindex an index with python with the following function

```
resp = client.reindex(
        body={
            "source": {
                "remote": {"host": "url_name:9200","username": "elastic","password": "password"},
                "index": "whateverindex",
                "query": {"match_all": {}}
            },
            "dest": {"index": "whateverindex"}
        }
    )
```

And I am getting

> BadRequestError(400, 'x_content_parse_exception', '[1:217] [reindex]
> failed to parse field [source]')

I've been trying to understand how come does elastic can't parse the source. It's a snippet of code that I took and modified a little (added user/password) from the [official documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/docs-reindex.html#reindex-from-remote).

Am I missing something ?

**EDIT :**

Code using the source and dest parameters as Val stated in the comments :

```
resp = client.reindex(
    source={
            "remote": {"host": "waked-kibana.cws.cines.fr:9200","username": "elastic","password": "VBcpxfR*HgMAs6-nf*4c"},
            "index": "covid19_api_arxiv_2012",
            "query": {"match_all": {}}
            }, 
    dest = {"index": "covid19_api_arxiv_2012"})
```

Still have a parseing error on Source.

Comment: Please read [the docs](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/v8.4.1/api.html#elasticsearch.Elasticsearch.reindex) on how to perform a reindex, there is no `body` parameter, but `source` and `dest`

Comment: I took this snippet of code from the official documentation you can find here. It's a 8.4 documentation. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.4/docs-reindex.html#reindex-from-remote

Comment: I tried using a source and a dest parameters. Since there is no example on how to do it from the ElasticSerach Python Client documentation, I guess I made a mistake because I still have the same errors. Would you mind taking a look ?

Answer (score 0):

the source.remote.host should start with http://
the source/dest keywords dont exist for the python client

```py
resp = client.reindex(
        body={
            "source": {
                "remote": {"host": "http://url_name:9200","username": "elastic","password": "password"},
                "index": "whateverindex",
            },
            "dest": {"index": "whateverindex"}
        }
    )
```